# Tensorflow and masking (labeling) images

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I'm trying to detect face using Tensorflow and Keras.  Dataset is [LFW Parts](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/part_labels/). Not interested in Open CV.

Example of dataset looks like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CGHc.jpg]
[image]

Would like to know the following:

1. If I understood it correctly, python script takes images and theirs masks, runs them through a model and save that model with weights. After that, if accuracy is high enough, predictor can be used to run totally unknown single image and get proper mask as a result. Right?
2. If I want to detect face only, with ears, and use LFW dataset, each mask should be edited, and some of the green part removed?
3. If that's the case, are there any tools for the job, that will do this automatically or be easy to use? Manual removal seem like a nightmare.
4. What about details of mask? In the example above, mask of hair is pretty rough. Will the machine learn ( pun intended ) to make details and eventually set exact hair, or it will remain like this?
5. Lets say object was added in front of face, like beard, glasses or hat. What will happen with detection? Will it simply cut it if beyond face edges, or it will detect that shape also? Do I need proper images and masks of that too?

Comment: This is too many questions and too broad, but anyway. 1) Yes, you train on images + labels and then predict the labels from the image only. 2, 3) If you are interested only in one of the labels, you can have a model that learns only that label (or preprocess the data to remove other labels); however if the given label does not match your needs, you need to modify the dataset. 4, 5) "what will the model do here" is almost impossible to respond, you have to run the experiments and test. In general, it will emulate the data (similar hair labels, if data has no glasses then those will fail, etc).

Comment: Thanks.

One quick question, based on image above. Let's say that example guy has a beard, and I want full foreground. Would result be the same if I take separate colors for each part, compared to result if everything wanted is green. Or it depends and should be tested :)? Point is, would it be stupid to just paint the foreground with one color and background with other?

Comment: If you have several labels, say `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, and you want to learn, for each pixel, "is this `A` or one of `B`, `C` or `D`?", or "is this one of `A` or `B` or one of `C` or `D`?", you should not have to do any manual processing. You can just preprocess the data to make all "equivalent" labels have the same value, or create a model with a single output (since it is a binary classification problem) and a loss function representing that. However, if the given labels are not defined as you need (e.g. beards are labelled as background) then would have to manually fix the dataset.